# Swift Xcode 13 Programmatic UITableViewController nil delegate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, delegation

The Delegated function fires but crashes as its nil, the objects in the items array is populated by CoreData, this `var model: CoreDataModel = CoreDataModel(CoreDataController.shared)` has to be instantiated rather than as expected in the viewDidLoad to prevent a nil error for the table view row count (model.items.count)

On startup the items array is the complete Sqlite DB, on search its the subset of the table and printing to the console proves the array is changed and only has the subset of Albums.

BaseViewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
}

protocol MasterModel {
    var client: LastFMClient { get }
    func searchFeed(with userSearchTerm: String?, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
}

protocol DataReloadTableViewDelegate: class {
    func reloadAlbumsTable()
}

class BaseViewController: UITableViewController, MasterModel {

    let cellId = "sdlfjowieurewfn3489844224947824dslaksjfs;ad"
    let logoContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    let image = UIImage(named: "lastFMRedBlack")
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    let client = LastFMClient()
    var model: CoreDataModel = CoreDataModel(CoreDataController.shared)
    private var searchResults: Root?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSearchController()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.register(SubtitleTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 72.5/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = image
        logoContainer.addSubview(imageView)
        navigationItem.titleView = logoContainer

        print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask))

        model.delegate = self
        model.fetchAllAlbums()
    }

    // MARK - SearchBar
    private func setupSearchController() {

        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Album"
        searchBar.delegate = self
        showSearchBarButton(shouldShow: true)
    }

    func showSearchBarButton (shouldShow: Bool) {

        if shouldShow {
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .search, target: self, action: #selector(handleShowSearchBar))

        } else {
            searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        }
    }

    func search(shouldShow: Bool) {
        showSearchBarButton(shouldShow: !shouldShow)
        navigationItem.titleView = shouldShow  ? searchBar : logoContainer
    }


    @objc func handleShowSearchBar(){

        search(shouldShow: true)
        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


    // MARK - API Request
    func searchFeed(with userSearchTerm: String?, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        // Use the API to get data
        client.getFeed(from: LastFMRequest.albumSearch(userSearchTerm: userSearchTerm) ) { result in

            switch result {
            case .success(let data):

                do {
                    let data = try DataParser.parse(data, type: RootNode.self)

                    self.searchResults = data.results
                    completion(true)

                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    completion(false)
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
}


extension BaseViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = nil
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        search(shouldShow:  false)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        guard let searchTextString = searchBar.text else { return }

        searchFeed(with: searchTextString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+").lowercased(), completion: {_ in

            if self.searchResults!.albumMatches.album.count == 0 {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Albums Found", message: "Try Another Keyword(s)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
                        print("Pressed OK")
                    }
                    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            } else {

                let dataManager = DataManager(data: self.searchResults!)
                do {
                    try dataManager.saveData()

                } catch {

                    print(error)
                }

            }
        })

        search(shouldShow:  false)
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

class SubtitleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension BaseViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    var numberOrSections: Int { return 1 }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        guard section >= 0 && section < numberOrSections else { return 0 }

        return model.items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        let albumItem = model.items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = albumItem.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = albumItem.value(forKeyPath: "artist") as? String

        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        // Populate the cell from the object
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vc = DetailViewController()
        let albumItem = model.items[indexPath.row]
        vc.iamgeURL = albumItem.value(forKeyPath: "imageUrl") as? String
        vc.albumName = albumItem.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }


}

extension BaseViewController: DataReloadTableViewDelegate {

    func reloadAlbumsTable(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(self.model.items.count)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }  
}
```

CoreDataModel

import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataModel {

```
weak var delegate: DataReloadTableViewDelegate?
let coreDataController: CoreDataController
var items:[Albums] = []

init(_ coreDataController: CoreDataController) {
    self.coreDataController = coreDataController
    self.coreDataController.mainContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
}

internal func saveSearchAlbums(responseData: Root) throws {

    let newSearch = Searches(context: coreDataController.mainContext)

    newSearch.searchQuery = responseData.attr.forField

    for (_, element) in responseData.albumMatches.album.enumerated() {

        let newAlbum = Albums(context: coreDataController.mainContext)

        let artistName = element.artist
        let albumName = element.name
        let imageUrlTwo = element.image[2].text
        let imageUrlZero = element.image[0].text
        let imageUrlOne = element.image[1].text

        var imageUrl: String = ""

        if !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrlTwo) {
            imageUrl = imageUrlTwo
        }

        if !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrlZero) {
            imageUrl = imageUrlZero
        }

        if !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrlOne) {
            imageUrl = imageUrlOne
        }

        if !JustLetters.blank(text: artistName) && !JustLetters.blank(text: albumName) && !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrl) {

            newAlbum.searches = newSearch
            newAlbum.artist = artistName
            newAlbum.name = albumName
            newAlbum.imageUrl = imageUrl

            newSearch.addToAlbums(newAlbum)
        }

    }
    // Save context
    coreDataController.saveContext()
    fetchAlbumsByKeyword(searchTerm: responseData.attr.forField)
}

internal func fetchAlbumsByKeyword(searchTerm: String) {

    // Create Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Albums")

    // Add Sort Descriptor
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Add Predicate
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchTerm)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {
        items = try  coreDataController.mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Albums]
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    delegate!.reloadAlbumsTable()
}

internal func fetchAllAlbums() {

    // Create the FetchRequest for all searches
    let allAlbums: NSFetchRequest = Albums.fetchRequest()

    do {
        items = try coreDataController.mainContext.fetch(allAlbums)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why have you defined `ResultsDataModel` instead of using `UITableviewDataSource`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to show your problem. You have a lot of CoreData, search bar stuff etc. in the code which probably is not relevant, but makes it really hard to read your code. Also, proper use of markdown to include all the code in code blocks would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you have edited your question to change the name of your protocol - the point is you shouldn't need to define a protocol at all because it is already part of UIKit.

Comment: The fact that you get a `nil` crash from the force unwrap indicates that you haven't set the delegate on that instance of the core data object. Set a breakpoint in the initialiser of that object and/or add a dissent to the delegate property and put a breakpoint in that

Comment: your comment prompted a thought, I had more than one instance of CoreDataModel, I set the delegate on the first instance on the viewDidLoad, the second instance is set on the search click but delegate must be set on class name and not on the instance id, refactored out the DataManager Class which itself createes and instance of CoreDataModel adn then the delegate is not nil, thanks @Paulw11

Comment: Do not include the answer in your question. Add an answer or delete the question.

Comment: moved @matt the reason I didn't put the answer in the 'answer' section was not to draw the ire of the community that this is staged.  Its already been downvoted as a poor question but in fact had I known this issue I would have ensured a single class at the cost of further code in the ViewController.

Comment: Answering your own question is standard, legal, and encouraged. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Modifying your question to include the answer is what draws ire. If you think the entire question-answer pair is not useful to others, delete the question; if you think the answer will be useful to others, answering your own question is correct. But _never_ answer in the question itself; a question is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is assigned/set on the class name and not on any instance identifier so a delegate can only be set on a class with one instance

I am unable to show specific proof, I rely on cause and effect of a single change to make the above statement.

I had more than one instance of CoreDataModel, I set the delegate on the first instance in the viewDidLoad, the second instance is set on the search click.  I refactored out the DataManager Class which itself creates and instance of CoreDataModel.

The final result is the delegate is not nil and performs as expected.  [Repo](https://bitbucket.org/ramblingbarney/perfect-tune) 'show_album_search_results' branch

Comment: I see no evidence in the question that this is right. `delegate` is an instance property, not a static or class property, in your question code.